# How to store a javascript array in PHP session?

Tags: php, javascript, json, session, client-server

I have an array in my javascript function having string values like 1,2,3,4... etc.
I want to store this array in PHP's session. I searched it and they say to use JSON but I am getting the way how to use JSON.

Suppose my array's name is: **myArray**
and I want to do something like this: **$_SESSION['myArray'] = myArray;**

Is there anyway of doing that? Please provide some working code sample if possible.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: you mean, _but I am **not** getting the way how to use JSON_?

Comment: json is just a string representation of a javascript object/array (ie: (J)ava(S)cript (O)bject (N)otation). Just assign the json string into a session var as you would any other var.

Comment: JSON would actually be easier option...

Comment: I am not getting that how to use JSON for this purpose. How to store an array into it and how to receive from it. I have not worked much in Javascript and PHP.

Comment: Please tell us your specific problem. Is it passing a JS array to PHP? Is it storing a PHP array into a session? Is it getting a PHP array back from session? Is it turning a PHP array into a javascript array? There is much you can do wrong, your question is just too broad - please ask only one question at once. TIA

Comment: It is simple. Storing a javascript array into session and then get it back from session in a php file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript is running on the client, your PHP is running on the server. You need to send the data over HTTP.

To get data from a JavaScript array to a PHP session you need to:

1. Serialise the data (either to a collection of inputs in a form, or to a string. The [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) can help with the latter so long as you don't have data types that JSON doesn't support).
2. Send the data to PHP (either by submitting a form, or using Ajax)
3. Read the data back in PHP (probably from `$_POST`)
4. Optionally deserialise it back to a data structure
5. Store it in `$_SESSION`

Comment: Thanx for the help. Please tell me the way to send data to PHP from Javascript. I mean how to submit form from Javascript?

Comment: `reference_to_form_in_dom.submit()`

Answer (score 0):

The way to *encode* a JSON object to php (associative) array is to use: `json_encode(JS_OBJECT_WHICH_IS_STRINGIFIED)`. To *decode* a JSON object, use `json_decode(PHP_ASSOC_ARRAY)`.

For example:

```
$arr = json_encode('{a:"b"}');  // will give $arr = ['a': 'b']
$js_object = json_decode($arr); // will return '{a:"b"}'
```

Comment: You mixed the functions. Plus your JSON string is wrong (the quotation marks around the 'a' are missing). This is how it works: `$phpArray = json_decode('{"a":"b"}', true); $jsonAgain = json_encode($phpArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Look at json_encode and json_decode. Basically use `json_decode` to turn a javascript array into a php array and `json_encode` to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to accomplish.

If you simply want to store something from JavaScript in PHP, then it makes since to assign to a string literal in PHP a JSON representation of your array.

You you want to actually manipulate the array data, then you'll need write code that will parse the array from JavaScript, save it in memory, and then later write out some JavaScript code containing your array.  This process is known as serialization/deserialization. I work in .net, and the .net framework contains built-in classes to do these tasks; I think it's likely that your framework does, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your JSON encoded JS array to a php file (through ajax or a simple form), then decode it with json_decode(); and finally save it in session.
So, first of all, something like this on your JS code:

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(your_array, null);
```

Then, pass `json_text` to your PHP file so you can save it like this:

```
$_SESSION['myArray'] = json_decode($_POST['json_string']);
```

Of course `$_POST['json_string']` depends on the name you gave to your parameter.

Answer (score -2):

to convert myArray to json:

```
var s = "[" = myArray.join + "]"
```

That's only going to work if myArray contains things that don't need quotes around them, like integers or floats.

There are javascript frameworks you can use that abstract away the problems of getting your values into json in your script, can't remember the name, but I've heard they can be worthwhile.  On the other hand, it's not a whole lot harder than what you see above, depending on what kind of values you're dealing with.

to get the json to the server:

```
document.getElementById("someHiddenElement").value = s;
```

Then your server side php can save the value in session.